# How to Get Commits Within a Time Period by an Author

Tags: git, bash, github

I've forked a git repository and committed some changes into it. I want to retrieve my "diff" withing a time period (start and end times) by me.

I've tried that script:

https://github.com/sils1297/configurations/blob/master/scripts/git/collect_authors_patches.sh

And also tried that one:

```
for i in `git log --author=Author_Name --since=2015-05-25 --until=2015-08-21 --pretty=oneline | sed 's/ .*//'`
do
    git format-patch -M -C -1 $i
done | tac > series
```

Comment: What about those attempts didn't work exactly?

Comment: They don't generate something. Here is my repo: https://github.com/kamaci/gora and dates are from 2015-05-25 to 2015-08-21.

Comment: Did you put your username/etc. in the `--author` argument? Because using `--author=kamaci` in that command gets me results here (on master).

Comment: Aaah, it was my mistake and they both works!